# Undefined: syscall.Kill on Windows

Tags: go, signals, sigkill

I'm using [eaburns/Watch](https://github.com/eaburns/Watch) library on a windows machine, but when trying to get the package with *go get github.com/eaburns/Watch* I get the following errors:

```
main.go:159: undefined: syscall.Kill
main.go:169: undefined: syscall.Wait4
main.go:169: undefined: syscall.WNOHANG
```

Any reason why this happens only on windows computers? How to fix this?

Comment: The package "github.com/eaburns/Watch" isn't compatible with windows.

Comment: Do you know any go package to do the same thing for windows?

Comment: No. How about combing something like [gopkg.in/fsnotify.v1](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/fsnotify.v1), and just run the commands yourself?

Answer (score 0):

The `syscall` package is dependent on the operating system. `syscall.Kill` is for Unix/Linux/Mac systems, not Windows.

Use `godoc` syscall to get information on the syscall package for your system. This is explained in the Overview section in the package documentation:

https://golang.org/pkg/syscall/